# i have problem with Laravel connection to data base

Tags: mysql, laravel

when I try `php artisan migrate`
it show me that error
my database is **mysql**

```
at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:822
    818▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    819▕                 );
    820▕             }
    821▕
  ➜ 822▕             throw new QueryException(
    823▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    824▕             );
    825▕         }
    826▕     }

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
      PDOException::("could not find driver")

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
      PDO::__construct()
```

I try to remove `;` from PHP file in xampp\php but it didn't work

Comment: are you using xampp on ubuntu or windows? and you're using php from xampp or you installed some php  beforehand? Also, did you remove from pdo_mysql only or you did it for mysqli also? After that, stop all services and start again in xampp

Comment: Also, check .env file for mysql user, password, ip, port - something might be wrong in there also

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the PDO MySQL extension in XAMPP:

- Locate your php.ini file. In XAMPP, it's usually found in
  xampp/php/php.ini.
- Open php.ini.
- Search (;extension=pdo_mysql).
- Remove the semicolon (extension=pdo_mysql).
- Save the php.ini file.
- Restart your Apache server.

Now you try to migrate command (php artisan migrate).

Comment: zabbir hossain 
first of all thank you for your try
second i try this and it also did not work

Comment: Same error showing?